# Who said "when I am changing film rolls there is no photograph"?

Tags: quotes

I might have gotten the quote wrong, because I cannot find it anywhere online, but it is something along the lines...

The context is that a famous photographer was asked how he felt about the photos he missed when changing film, and he replied that there were no photos while he was changing film.

If my memory serves me well it was an American photographer who shot documentary photography on 35mm film.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know why, but as soon as I read your quote, it struck me as something [Garry Winogrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Winogrand) might have said – maybe because of his shooting style. I googled for quotes by him, and there it is right away...

From https://photoquotes.com/author/garry-winogrand:

> When asked how he felt about missing photographs while he reloaded his
> camera with film, he replied "There are no photographs while I'm
> reloading".

Comment: Thank you so much! It was driving me crazy... Add a fun side note, ChatGPT was very adamant it was Henry Cartier-Bresson who said that 

Comment: @fortran Asking ChatGPT about factual questions is a big no-no knowing its tendency to hallucinate. It can still formulate and elaborate well, or rephrase something in a specific style but relying on it for information is a huge mistake.

Comment: "...relying on it is a huge mistake" <-- fixed that for ya, @zovits ;)

Comment: I assumed that it the phrase was common knowledge but with a different wording it might have no trouble doing the match... But yes, I am very aware of its tendency to hallucinate and double down on made up things xD